# How to detect if CloudinaryField in django model is empty in template

Tags: django, django-models, cloudinary

```
picture = CloudinaryField('image', blank = True, null = True)
```

I have the above line in my django models file. And I am rendering the picture in my template with the cloudinary tag

```
{% cloudinary "filename" %}
```

But in cases where the model objects don't contain the picture, I want to forgo the template tag. Right now, my template renders a empty image if the model instance doesn't have a picture.

How can I detect if the model instance contains a picture, so that I can render it selectively using the `

```
{% if condition %}
```

Answer (score 0):

`None`, `True`, `False` are available in Django templates. So you can do something similar to -

`{% if photo.picture == None %}`

or

`{% if not photo.picture %}`

That said, It's not clear as to why allow null values in this field in the first place. This field should contain all relevant details of the image for further manipulation and delivery.